# how can I correct addition function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in output. For example, 2+3 = 23 instead of 5.

```js
function addition() {
  var v1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  var v2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = v1 + v2;
}
```

Comment: Make the values *numbers*.

Comment: var v1=parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
     var v2=parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);

     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = v1+v2;

Comment: `v1` and `v2` are both strings.  Adding strings concatenates them.

Comment: You need to learn JavaScript basics, have a look at [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators).

Answer (score 0):

`v1` and `v2` are strings, which means adding them concatenates them.

Instead, turn `v1` and v2` into numbers.

```js
function addition() {
  var v1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
  var v2=document.getElementById("n2").value;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Number(v1) + Number(v2);
}
```

```html
<input id = "n1" value = "2">
<input id = "n2" value = "3"><br>
<button onCLick = "addition()">Add Numbers</button>
<p id = "demo"></p>
```

You can also use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` instead of `Number()` if they don't have to be strictly numbers.